# How do I refer to the type of an ascx by type name?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I just discovered a very obscure feature in ASP.NET that allows control to be mapped to another control. This can be very useful if you don't have the source to a control, but you want to replace it with a custom control with minimal impact on the source. Essentially, it works like a ControlAdapter except that the entire type is remapped into another type. You only need to modify your web.config file:

```
   <pages>
      <tagMapping>
         <add
            tagType=
               "System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager"
            mappedTagType=
               "Microsoft.Sharepoint.WebPartPartManager, 
                MSPS.Web.dll, Version='2.0.0.0'" 
         />
      </tagMapping>
   </pages>
```

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The tagMapping element defines a collection of tag types that are
>   remapped to other tag types at compile time. This remapping causes the
>   mapped type to be used in place of the original tag type for all pages
>   and controls in the ASP.NET application within the scope of the
>   configuration file.

I am able to map a UserControl instead of a standard control, but my replacement UserControl isn't displaying.

I realize that I am referring to the wrong type. In order for this to work, I would have to refer to ASPX type name and not the type it inherits from. Could this be what's causing the problem, if so how do I find the type of the ascx?

UPDATE:
Richard provided me with an excellent clue towards an answer. Unfortunately, I am still left with two problems:

First, although Richard's ClassName suggestion gives me a consistent name for my ascx, the other control I am replacing doesn't use the attribute. I want to avoid messing with the third party code and I don't know what side effects it will have. However, I can use the ASP.NET generated ClassName provided it doesn't change upon compilation or execution environment.

Second, since both type names are generated at runtime instead of compile time, the web.config freaks out claiming it cannot load the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`@Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d19c0t4b.aspx) directive in the control (`.ascx`) to define the typename of the control with the `ClassName` attribute. Eg.

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" ClassName='MyNamespace.MyControl" %>
```

Comment: If the `.ascx` doesn't specify a type name, then one is generated when the `.ascx` is compiled. I suspect (check at runtime) this will not be consistent. If it is third party code then raise a defect that it is not specified.

Comment: @user148298: See previous comment (forgot to put your name in.)

Comment: Thanks again. The third party control doesn't specify one and it doesn't have to, since they recommend modifying a copy of the ascx. Regardless, the ClassNames are unavailable since they are not compiled until runtime.